# i trying to use Google Maps Android API and i get error :

Tags: java, android, google-maps, cmd

i post this code (same in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#displaying_certificate_information ) in my cmd

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\PC\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

and i get this error

```
 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

any help ?

Comment: Keytool is not on your path. But if this problem is something that you can't solve alone, armed with Google in one hand and [SO] on the other, you really miss a lot of basic context.

Comment: What is your path to key tool that must be some thing like this 
C:\...\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\keytool

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html and this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html

Comment: Are you Using Eclipse ?

Comment: ppeterka >>> yes im Beginner in Developing Android ... Usman Kurd >> i cant understand You ... Jitesh Dalsaninya >>> yes im using Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to locate your directory which is contains keytool file. For that check below:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin` **OR** navigate to your java installed directory.

AND then write your command

```
  keytool -list -keystore "C:\Users\MyPcName\.android\debug.keystore"
```

LIKE,

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin>keytool -list -keystore "C:\Users\MyPcName\.android\debug.keystore".
```

Comment: have you navigate properly to your jdk/bin directory??

Answer (score 0):

Check that the directory the keytool executable is in is on your path. (For example, on my Windows 7 machine, it's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin`.)